# Kubernetes network-policy does not do any effect

Tags: kubernetes, nginx, minikube, kubernetes-networkpolicy

i started minikube with this command

```
minikube start --network-plugin=cni --cni=calico
```

and i create nginx pod in default namespace with this file

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: web
spec:
  containers:
  - image: nginx
    imagePullPolicy: Always
    name: nginx
    ports:
    - containerPort: 80
      protocol: TCP
```

and i create a pod in qa namespace to curl the nginx in default namespace with this file

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: curl-pod
spec:
  containers:
  - name: curlpod
    image: radial/busyboxplus:curl
    command:
    - sh
    - -c
    - while true; do sleep 1; done
```

when i curl it works well,

after that i need to deny ingress traffic to the nginx pod in my default namespace
so i apply this networkpolicy

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: NetworkPolicy
metadata:
  name: default-deny-ingress
spec:
  podSelector: {}
  policyTypes:
  - Ingress
```

but this does not do any thing when i curl from pod in qa namespace it return response 200 ok

and i don't know how can i fix that, can any one help me.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try changing your minikube start command to this:

```
minikube start --cni=false --network-plugin=cni

kubectl create -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/projectcalico/calico/v3.26.3/manifests/tigera-operator.yaml

kubectl create -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/projectcalico/calico/v3.26.3/manifests/custom-resources.yaml
```

Then verify that Calico is installed and running:

```
watch kubectl get pods -l k8s-app=calico-node -A
```

If you want a gloabl default deny (all namespaces) try this:

```
apiVersion: projectcalico.org/v3
kind: GlobalNetworkPolicy
metadata:
  name: default-deny
spec:
  selector: all()
  types:
    - Ingress
    - Egress
```

If you want it namespaced to your default ns, try this:

```
apiVersion: projectcalico.org/v3
kind: NetworkPolicy
metadata:
  name: default-deny
  namespace: default
spec:
  selector: all()
  types:
    - Ingress
    - Egress
```

Comment: when i tried it i got this error 
error: resource mapping not found for name: "default-deny" namespace: "default" from "block-other-namespace.yaml": no matches for kind "NetworkPolicy" in version "projectcalico.org/v3"
ensure CRDs are installed first

Comment: and when i run kubectl get crd
i see this 
networkpolicies.crd.projectcalico.org

Comment: @AhmedZedan did you reinstall minikube/calico from scratch before trying the new policies? And to get nginx, you only applied the yaml file you posted, you didn't run '''minikube addons enable ingress''' or anything else? So I have all the info if I wanna test this myself?
https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/ingress-minikube/

Comment: yes, i reinstall minikube/calico and i didn't run '''minikube addons enable ingress''' i don't know why i need this or this is required. does i need it here because i use nginx image? if yes that mean i don't need it if i use another image or what ?
can you explain it to me, please?